# Getting current hour from UTC Offset with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs, timezone-offset

I would like to convert a utc offset value (e.g. `"-1000"`) into the given hour, (e.g. `2pm`). How do I do this with `mommentjs`? Is there a way to do this without using `momentjs timzone`? I was previously trying the following but not getting the expected outcome.

`moment.parseZone("-1000").format('h A')`

Comment: Having more of your code available would help. Can you post an expanded view of the snippet, with all of the related variable declarations included?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  A UTC offset does not tell you the time.  Simply put, `-1000` does not equal `2 pm`. Rather, a UTC offset tells you how far a given local time is positioned away from UTC.  For it to be 2 pm (14:00) in UTC-10:00, it would have to be 12 am (00:00) in UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`utcOffset`](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/09-utc-offset/) accepts a minute-based offset value do just that. If "-1000" is referring to 10 hour offset, then -600 would be the number of minutes to offset.

```
moment().utcOffset(-600).format('h A')
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  passing `utcOffset(-1000)` will set an offset of `UTC-16:40`, as numeric offsets will be treated as a number of minutes from UTC. (1000 minutes is 16 hour and 40 minutes.)

Comment: @MattJohnson You're right, I misred the question and assumed for some reason that the 1000 was already referring to minutesand not to (most likely) UTC-10:00

Comment: One could also pass `"-1000"` (as a string) and get the same result.  Still, I'm not sure exactly what the OP actually wants, as their assertion "-1000 = 2pm" is invalid.